# PHP & MySQL - Which variable type best for this array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, int

Question: Stated in title

Project: My PHP Mafia/Mobsters Strategy Game

Reason for Asking: I'm unsure how I would word this question into a somewhat relevant Google search.

I would like to know which MySql variable type I should use for an array. I will explode this array into an ID list including all people in that players mob.

EXAMPLE MYSQL DATA BELOW:

```
PlayerId -------- Mob //Lables

134 ------------- '23','59','12','53','801' //Values
```

This will then be exploded using `explode()` in PHP into a bunch of ints containing the IDS of players in that persons mob.

I would like the mob field to have an unlimited character length so that players can have HUGEE mobs.

I think I may be able to simply use `longtext` or the `set` type but I'm not completely sure. I don't want any errors later on once I release the game and I want my methods to stay clean and correct.

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this, I hope you can help. :)

Comment: Is doing an n-to-m relation out of the question? Or actually, 1-to-n might suffice, seeing that one player can only be in one mob, right? That way, you could make the database do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @Grüse: It appears to me that, far from "one player only being in one mob", PlayerId `134` above is in five mobs.

Comment: @eggyal: You're right, I seem to have misunderstood the concept of a Mafia mob membership and its seemingly non-exclusive nature ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a very long time ago, but I happened to come across the question when browsing through my account.

There aren't any specific "mobs." Your "mob" is basically like a friends list. It's not a group. It's just a bunch of people connected to you.

I believe I simply made a row for "mob members" and just put the other players ids, separated by commas, then in the PHP I exploded the string with a comma as the delimiter.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a table that associates players with mobs:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE PlayerMobs (
   PlayerId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   MobId    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (PlayerID) REFERENCES Players (PlayerID),
   FOREIGN KEY (MobID)    REFERENCES Mobs    (MobID)
);
```

And then [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) it with your other tables in queries as required.

I have added [`FOREIGN KEY` constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to ensure that only valid `PlayerID` and `MobID` values exist in the `PlayerMobs` table, but note that these constraints currently only work with the `InnoDB` storage engine.

Comment: Exactly, or - if a player can only be in one mob at any given time - you could add a "MobId" column in your Player table that saves this player's mob allegiance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 CREATE TABLE PlayerMobs (
 PlayerId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 MobId   Text UNSIGNED NOT NULL);
```